How to plot $|z^2 -2|\leq 1 $ in the complex plane?
How do plot the subset $|z^2 -2|\leq 1 $ in the complex plane? I have gone through 'Foundations of Complex Analysis by S. Ponnusamy' but didn't get any idea as how to solve it. This problem is from the practice question bank of Mumbai University.
I tried doing it by taking $z = x+iy$.
Then we get,
$$|x^2 - y^2 + i2xy -2|\leq 1$$
$$\therefore (x^2 - y^2-2)^2 + 4x^2y^2 \leq 1^2$$
$$\therefore (x^2-y^2)^2 -4(x^2-y^2)+4+ 4x^2y^2\leq 1$$
$$\therefore (x^2+y^2)^2-4x^2+4y^2\leq -3.$$
$$\therefore x^4 + y^4 + 2x^2 y^2 -4x^2 + 4y^2 \leq -3.$$ But how should I plot this? I can't recall anything standard which resembles this form ?
Edit 1: As suggested by @Pedro sir in comments, polar coordinates yields:
$$r^4(cos^4\theta +sin^4\theta +2sin^2\theta cos^2\theta)-4r^2(cos^2\theta -sin^2\theta)\leq -3.$$
$$\therefore r^4 - 4r^2cos2\theta\leq -3.$$
But I am still stuck as how to proceed further.
Edit 2: As suggested by Mr. Tian Vlasic, the above equation reduces to :
$$ (x^2+y^2+2)^2-4-4(x^2+y^2)-4x^2+4y^2\leq -3.$$
$$\therefore (x^2+y^2+2)^2-4(2)x^2\leq 1.$$
$$\therefore (x^2+y^2+(\sqrt2)^2)^2-4(\sqrt2)^2x^2\leq 1^2.$$
Which is indeed the area bounded by a Cassini oval of eccentricity $e=\sqrt2$. This solves my query. Thanks to all who commented !

Maybe try polar coordinates?

If your calculations are correct, your curve is the area bounded by a Cassini oval of eccentricity $e=\sqrt{2}$.

you don't recall anything standard because it is not standard

This is indeed a Cassini oval, because you can write $|z-\sqrt{2}|\cdot|z+\sqrt{2}|\le 1$, which means that the product of the distance from $z$ to the points $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ is lower than 1. Equality defines a Cassini oval. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval

@FrancescoPeña-Garcia ... "Ovals of Cassini" is standard, in my opinion.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval

The argument proves that taking any quadratic polynomial instead of $z^2-2$ gives a Cassini oval.

@Gribouillis I think your argument only generalizes to quadratic polynomials of positive discriminants.

@TianVlašić No it generalizes to any complex quadratic polynomial, because you can always factor $|a z^2 + b z + c|$ as $|a||z-z_0||z-z_1|$ where $z_0, z_1$ are the complex roots, now the focal points of the Cassini oval.

Sorry, I believe you are correct, yes. All the shapes will correspond to Cassini ovals.
